# SQL Server always Stopped

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

While connecting to SQL Server 2012, I am getting the following error.

> An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2012, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Here is what I did:

I installed SQL Server Management Studio normally but I can't get the server running. How do I set SQL Server correctly the first time?

I want to be able to install this server in my desktop locally and connect to it using Microsoft SQL Server. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
[Screenshot of my server status as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0j6F.png)

Comment: Did you try starting the service?

Comment: I did. I get the following error: The request failed or server did not respond in timely fashion. Please consult the log. 
I don't know where to locate the log.

Comment: First check event viewer, then check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: You can check in the event viewer to see the events being logged when you try to start the service. I could be the reason that the user under which the service is running does not have the privilege. You can set the "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER" as the owner of the service.

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer start - Log on as LocalSystem

You can try to replace the system databases with you system databases from somewhere else. If not, you can control the firewall.

If you are connecting from the remote server, you check this are.
From the section SQL Server Network Configuration;

TCP/IP Port : 1433 , Named Pipes : Enabled and restart SQLServer